# how to extract a phone number for a string using regular expression?

Tags: java, regex, string

If I have a string that contains the following: **This is 1 test 123-456-7890** 
I need to extract **1234567890** as a phone number. I don't want to extract the number 1 that is before test. 
How can I do that using regular expressions in java?

I know a way but I am not sure if it is the best solution:

```
String inputString = "This is 1 test 123-456-7890";
string result =  inputString.replaceAll("(\\d{3})-(\\d{3})-(\\d{4})",""); 
String phoneNumber = inputString.replace(result, "");
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? Your requirements are a bit vague since since I don't know if the following will pass either "123456 1234567890". Unless you can format your input you are going to struggle to get your output correct (since it appears you have a free-type input)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The following code will check for the phone number in the string you mention and print it:

```
String str = "This is 1 test 123-456-7890";

Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(str);
if (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

But, as pointed out in other answers, many phone numbers (especially not international ones) will not match the pattern.

Answer (score 14):

The best and standard way is use [libphonenumber](https://github.com/googlei18n/libphonenumber). There is a [findNumbers](https://libphonenumber.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/i18n/phonenumbers/PhoneNumberUtil.html#findNumbers(java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.String)) function  you can use. Here is a code snippet

```
public static void  extractPhoneNumber(String input){


    Iterator<PhoneNumberMatch> existsPhone=PhoneNumberUtil.getInstance().findNumbers(input, "IN").iterator();

    while (existsPhone.hasNext()){
        System.out.println("Phone == " + existsPhone.next().number());
    }
}
```

Comment: Worth to mention that this lib is from Google, so... you got the idea.

Comment: Cool!!! I'm using this library. Didn't even know this exists! Thanks!!!

Answer (score 6):

First of all, please note that there is no *simple* way to do this *properly* with regular expressions, because there is **no single universally accepted format convention for phone numbers**.

For example all of the following are correctly formatted phone numbers:

```
+1-555-2345
+358(0)1234567
02 500 500
+31 44 55 66 77
123-456-7890
+82 (0) 77 233 ext. 3456
(09) 223 44 ext 123
```

I'm sure there are plenty more formats that are the local convention.

If there is nothing after the phone number on the text line, I would go for `.*[^0-9-( )] ([0-9-( )]+)$`, which matches from the end of the line.

Otherwise, I would search for all occurences of `([0-9-( )]+)` and *hope* that there is only one match *per entry* (I suppose you have some sort of entry boundaries in your data) that is long enough (9+ characters) to be a phone number and choose that.

Neither of these approaches accept numbers that have `ext` in them.

Comment: That is a good question. I didn't even considered international numbers when i post my answer.

Comment: You can combine regex see https://www.baeldung.com/java-regex-validate-phone-numbers

Answer (score 2):

```
(\d{3})-(\d{3})-(\d{4})
```

that will find xxx-xxx-xxxx, if you need other combination, adjust {x} for how many numbers you want to see such as xxxxxxxxxx (\d{10})

Here is an example with code on how to use regex and get results:

http://www.exampledepot.com/egs/java.util.regex/BasicMatch.html

Comment: I don't just want to find or see if it exists, I already know how to do that. but my problem is to save the result (phone number) into a new variable

Comment: So u r not asking for a regular expression, u r asking how to use regular expression in java. Question is, what have you tried, and post the code.

Comment: @Wael: Add it to your question, don't put it in a comment.

Answer (score 1):

```
mobile_number = PhoneNumberUtils.stripSeparators(mobile);
```

PhoneNumberUtils class gives different functions for phone number formatting operations. with stripSeparators function you can remove all type of formatting and get exact integer number.